# properties of a matrix which not negative definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that if a matrix is not negative definite, then there exists a row $i$ which the sum of its entries $\sum _j a_{ij}$ is positive?

Comment: The zero matrix contradicts this...

Comment: Perhaps you mean "not non-positive definite"?

Comment: No. You're asking: if all row sums are nonnegative, must the matrix be negative (semi)definite? But all row sums being nonnegative just means that the matrix maps $(1,1,\dots,1)$ into the nonnegative orthant. It can map other vectors anywhere you decide. For example, find a $2\times2$ matrix that maps $(1,1)$ to $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,0)$ to $(1,0)$.